# How to deploy web application onto Google App Engine

Tags: eclipse, web-services, google-app-engine, tomcat, web-deployment

This may be a vague question but I have been unable to find any help/tutorials specific to my situation and am stuck.

I have built a website using Eclipse (Dynamic Web Project.) I then deployed this application using Tomcat and can see it by going to localhost, however, I am struggling on how to actually deploy it to the cloud.

I am trying to use Google App Engine but am open to other (free) alternatives for deploying my web application.

With Google App Engine, I registered for an account, made a new project, connected it to my github repository and confirmed the correct code is listed.

However, when navigating to project_id.appspot.com (mine is http://mapp-development.appspot.com) I get a 404 error.

I have attempted various deployments and even made an entirely new Google Web Application Project in Eclipse for testing which worked but weirdly deployed to http://1-dot-mapp-develop.appspot.com/ and is the test files which I do not know how to correctly modify.

Is there any way to upload/deploy my existing web application to Google App Engine (as a .war or otherwise)?

I am new to web development and apologize for any unclear specifications. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have also tried (in Eclipse) right clicking the project and choosing "Deploy to App Engine" under Google however it states "mapp-website is not an App Engine project".

Edit2: I had a stupid mistake, I confused my Project ID (mapp-development) and app id (mapp-develop). I am able to successfully make a new Google web project and deploy it to mapp-develop.appspot.com

Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three ways to deploy:

1. Make an App Engine project in [Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse)
2. Deploy via [Git](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.jp/2013/07/google-app-engine-hello-world-using.html)
3. Deploy via [GitHub](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.jp/2014/04/using-github-for-push-to-deploy.html)

It seems like you tried #1 with a project named `1-dot-mapp-develop`.  If you select deploy from Eclipse, a dialog box will pop up with a link to "App Engine Project Settings" where you can change the project name (to `mapp-development` and version).

Comment: `1-dot-mapp-develop` is actually just version 1 of `mapp-develop` (transmogrified to avoid subdomains so you can use HTTPS if you so desire -- `1.mapp-develop.appspot.com` would be the normal URL but then, being a subdomain, you don't get a SSL certificate for it, hence, no HTTPS).

Comment: Thank you, it was very confusing seeing all the different ways to publish, wasn't sure if I had to do them all.

I am now successfully using the first option, it is pretty easy; I will look into the other options later.

Thanks for the help!